# Custom jQuery plugin but can't figure out custom methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, methods

I'm rewriting a plugin so that each main section is turned into a `method` [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891553/594235) and [the jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), and so far the whole thing is still working.

The plugin is initialized with:

```
$('#mySelector').myPlugin({
    // want to keep initial options
    option1: true,
    option2: 'right'
    // etc.
});
```

Then later, I want to use a `refresh` method:

```
$('#mySelector').myPlugin('refresh');
```

Basically, I need "refresh" to do everything in this plugin, *except* re-applying the HTML DOM modifications (while keeping all of the original initialized options).

I can't seem to figure it out.  I cannot just use `methods.binders(var1, var2);` because I need to get the variables too.  However, the `init()` needs the `methods.html()` when it's first initialized.  How can I skip that one part when I do my `refresh`?

Maybe it's simple, but I have a headache now.

```
(function ($) {

    var methods = {
        defaults : {
            option1: false,
            option2: 'left'
                    // etc.
        },
        settings : {},
        init : function(options) {
            methods.settings = $.extend({}, methods.defaults, options);

            $(this).each(function() {
                if ($(this).is('[type=radio]')) {
                    var var1 = $(this);
                    var var2 = $('.somethingelse');
                    // etc.
                    methods.html(var1, var2);
                    methods.binders(var1, var2);
                };
            });

        },
        refresh : function () {
            // no idea??
        },
        html : function(var1, var2) {
            // various HTML DOM manipulations
        },
        binders : function(var1, var2) {
            // binding various events, hover, click, etc.
            // assigns classes
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin' );
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following moves most of the code from `methods.init` to a function `doInit()` that can be called in both `methods.init` and `methods.refresh` with argument for `initType` and a conditional inside to call some code for `init` but not `refresh`

```
(function($) {    

    var methods = {     
        /* see answer edit about moving this out of here*/        
        defaults: {
            option1: false,
            option2: 'left'
            // etc.
        },
        settings: {},
        init: function(options) {  
           /* see answer edit about moving this out of here*/
            methods.settings = $.extend({}, methods.defaults, options);
            doInit(this, 'init', methods);

        },
        refresh: function() {
            doInit(this, 'refresh', methods);
        },
        html: function(var1, var2) {
            // various HTML DOM manipulations
        },
        binders: function(var1, var2) {
            // binding various events, hover, click, etc.
            // assigns classes
        }
    };

    function doInit(el, initType, methods) {
        $(el).each(function() {
            if ($(this).is('[type=radio]')) {
                var var1 = $(this);
                var var2 = $('.somethingelse');
                // etc.
                methods.html(var1, var2);
                if (initType == 'init') {
                    methods.binders(var1, var2);
                }
            };
        });
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin');
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

May not be bug free but idea should get you going

EDIT: Realized I forgot to make the settings more global. One way is to remove defaults from `methods` and create

```
  var defaults={  /* ..... */};
 $.fn.myPlugin.defaults=$.extend({},defaults, options);
```

Now you have access to the user defined settings when you do the refresh. Another really helpful addition is to store the settings in jQuery DOM data like:

```
   $(this).data('myPlugin.settings', {/* extended settings object*/});
```

Comment: Thank-you.  I'm going to recover for a day or two and take a closer look at this.  Meanwhile +1.